# Docker-Compose - Server exposes several ports but only one of the ports is not accessible in the client

Tags: docker, docker-compose

New to Docker.

I have 2 containers which I'm linking through docker-compose.  Let's call them server & client.  The server exposes several ports.

When I execute `docker-compose up` and access the **client** via `docker exec` I can access all the ports except 1.

This particular port is an `IPC` port (as far as I know it is tcp based).

When I access the **server** via `docker exec`, I see the port is up and running and the underlying service is listening and responding to requests from the port.

I can even see that the port is running from the **host** (on the host I can run `nc -zv localhost 8020` -> success [please note that since port 8020 is being mapped to 8020 I can use localhost 8020]).

```
client
 image: my/client
 links: 
  - server

server:
 image: my/server
 ports:
  - "8020:8020" 
  - "50070:50070"
  - "50075:50075"
  - "50030:50030"
 expose:
  - "8020"
  - "50070"
  - "50075"
  - "50030"
```

The only port I cannot access is 8020.  In the client when I execute nmap, I get:

```
[root@ecc57bcc52b7 /]# nmap -p 8020 server

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-28 07:03 UTC
Nmap scan report for server (172.17.0.187)
Host is up (0.000058s latency).
rDNS record for 172.17.0.187: server
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8020/tcp closed unknown
MAC Address: 02:42:AC:11:00:BB (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

But all other ports report as open.

To reiterate, I'm 100% sure that port 8020 is being listened to in the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to check those issues:

1. On Host use: `telnet 172.17.42.1 8020` to make sure port 8020 is open on host machine.
2. In docker server container : `telnet 127.0.0.1 8020`, make sure port 8020 is open in docker container.
3. Check firewall on Host (iptables -L if you're using Linux machine).
4. Make sure in Host, there isn't service which is listening on port 8020.

Comment: not sure what value the telnet command adds since I've used nmap & nc already to check the port.  As explained above this is an issue between two linked containers...not host-container...if it is a firewall issue then why can i access the port through the host but not the linked client-container?  Thanks